# How to load image from URL in QML not in QT C++

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, qnx

This is my code and i want  to load image                                                                                                                                          from the given URL please tell if there is any way .becasue this is not loading the image

```
 ImageView {

            imageSource: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Toda_Hut.JPG"
            preferredWidth: 610
            translationY: 70.0
            translationX: 70.0
            preferredHeight: 250
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BB10 Does not currently support a URL for an ImageView.  There was mentions during the beta stage that it was coming but it is no longer listed on the roadmap.

--edit: As per Kernald - this feature is still in the roadmap.

Javascript does not support direct downloading of files which means you will have to  implement some c++ if you want to accomplish this.

The best example of this is from one of the official examples here:
https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/imageloader

You should be able to copy some of the c++ classes and implement it into your app without too much difficulty, even if your knowledge of c++ is weak.

Comment: It has been delayed, but it's still listed: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/roadmap/

Comment: My bad, couldn't find it when I looked a few weeks back, perhaps it was just accidentally removed for a short period.

Comment: Or you maybe watched the native roadmap: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/roadmap/ ;-)

Comment: what is connecting the question with this BlackBerry related answer? It is 2022 an BB is literally dead as well as the roadmap links.